# Vectorizing a Vector-Valued Function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following function:

```
def h_Y1(X, theta):
    EF = X[0]
    FF = X[1]
    j = X[-2]
    k = X[-1]
    W = X[2:-2]
    Sigma = theta[0]
    sigma_xi2 = theta[1]
    gamma_alpha = theta[2]
    gamma_z = np.array(theta[3:])
    gW = gamma_z @ W
    eps1 = EF -  gamma_alpha * gW
    if j == k:
        eps2 = FF - (gamma_alpha**2)*gW - gW*sigma_xi2 - Sigma
        eps3 = 0
    else:
        eps2 = 0
        eps3 = FF - (gamma_alpha**2)*gW
    h1 = [eps1 * Wk for Wk in W]
    h2 = [eps2 * Wk for Wk in W]
    h3 = [eps3 * Wk for Wk in W]
    return np.concatenate([h1, h2, h3])
```

I need to execute the function for a range of values, which are stored in `gmmarray`. Specifically, I'd like the function to be run for each row of `gmmarray` as the function argument `X`, for a fixed `theta`.

I'm currently doing this using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
theta = [0.01, 1, 1, 0, 0]
gmmarray = np.random.random((1120451, 6))
test = np.apply_along_axis(h_Y1, 1, gmmarray, theta = init)
```

However, this is slow - it takes around 19 seconds. I tried vectorizing the function as follows:

```
Vh_Y1 = np.vectorize(h_Y1, signature = '(n),(j)->(i)')
test1 = Vh_Y1(gmmarray, init)
```

However, this still takes 16 seconds. Am I doing something wrong here or is there a way to speed things up further?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the shape of `gmmarray`? How many elements is `X` supposed to have? What about the shape of `theta`? Could you post example `gmmarray` and `theta` values, please?

Comment: Hi @AJH - sorry about that! See updated question now for an example.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` and `np.vectorize` are not speed tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the full `gmmarray` as the `X` parameter. Then, instead of looping through each row of `gmmarray`, you can use vectorized operations on its columns.

Something like this:

```
def h_Y1_vectorized(X, theta):
    EF, FF, W, j, k = np.hsplit(X, [1,2,4,5])         # Column vectors (except W)
    Sigma, sigma_xi2, gamma_alpha, *gamma_z = theta

    gW = (W @ gamma_z)[:, None]                       # Ensure column vector
    ga_gW = gamma_alpha * gW
    FF_ga2gW = FF - gamma_alpha * ga_gW

    eps1 = EF - ga_gW
    j_equal_k = j == k
    eps2 = np.where(j_equal_k, FF_ga2gW - gW * sigma_xi2 - Sigma, 0)
    eps3 = np.where(j_equal_k, 0, FF_ga2gW)

    h1 = eps1 * W
    h2 = eps2 * W
    h3 = eps3 * W

    return np.hstack([h1, h2, h3])
```

Calling

```
>>> h_Y1_vectorized(gmmarray, theta)
```

produces the same result with roughly a 100x speed increase.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you so much!

Comment: What exactly does ``np.vectorize`` do in this case then and why am I getting any (albeit very small) speedup?